# WooCommerce form fields switch order of label and input

Tags: php, jquery

In Woocommerce, the default order of the form fields is to display as follows:

```
<label>Field label</label>
<input type="text" value="Field value">
```

However, I want to reverse these to displays as:

```
<input type="text" value="Field value">
<label>Field label</label>
```

I have been unable to achieve via PHP (preferred), and have instead achieved it via jQuery, which feels a bit 'hacky'. In addition, I can't use any CSS solutions as what I'm trying to achieve relies on the order of the DOM elements.

```
jQuery('form.woocommerce label').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).insertAfter(jQuery(this).parent().find('input'));
})
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Not really. `$(this).insertAfter($(this).next('input'));` is about as simple as it gets for this - but that assumes the elements are always immediate siblings

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without even php or js. Simply find the template you want to tweak for example my case. You go to plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php take your desired .php template and create a structure like this (preferably child theme):
yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php or being specific childtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php
Then simply tweak the html/php the way you want. Benefits, your theme files will not be overwritten after plugin update, no need for js usage, simple solution.